# Accessing dataframes after splitting a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm splitting a dataframe in multiple dataframes using the command

```
data <- apply(data, 2, function(x) data.frame(sort(x, decreasing=F)))
```

I don't know how to access them, I know I can access them using df$`1` but I have to do that for every dataframe,

```
  df1<- head(data$`1`,k)
  df2<- head(data$`2`,k)
```

can I get these dataframes in one go (like storing them in some form) however the indexes of these multiple dataframes shouldn't change.

str(data) gives

```
List of 2
 $ 7:'data.frame':  7 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ sort.x..decreasing...F.: num [1:7] 0.265 0.332 0.458 0.51 0.52 ...
 $ 8:'data.frame':  7 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ sort.x..decreasing...F.: num [1:7] 0.173 0.224 0.412 0.424 0.5 ...
```

str(data[1:2])

```
List of 2
 $ 7:'data.frame':  7 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ sort.x..decreasing...F.: num [1:7] 0.265 0.332 0.458 0.51 0.52 ...
 $ 8:'data.frame':  7 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ sort.x..decreasing...F.: num [1:7] 0.173 0.224 0.412 0.424 0.5 ...
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the question but you access elements of the list with data[[1]] (returns a data frame) or data[1:2] (returns a list.

Comment: what do you think your first statement is actually doing/trying to do? (you might want to try running `str(data)` to see what that generated b/c I do not think it's doing what you think it is or want it to)

Comment: Not sure what your aim is (you might want to explain that - I think you are taking a detour)

Comment: @timcdlucas but this statement doesn't work data<- head(data[1:2],3) it still gives all the elements

Comment: melissa, as @hrbrmstr suggested, see what `str(data)` and then `str(data[1:2])` give you so you can figure out how to work with it. It's generally a good idea, when dealing with a number of identical data.frames, to put them in a list like this (most programmers don't grok this), so your next step is to learn to apply a function to each data.frame within a list. These functions might be useful: `sapply`, `lapply`, `rbind` (specifically `do.call("rbind", list_of_dataframes)`, alternatively `dplyr::bind_rows`).

Comment: @RichardTelford tbh I think so too I just wanted to confirm since I'm new in R, I had dataframe with two columns and I wanted to sort them (both 2 columns in decreasing order) and maintain their respective indexes it wasn't possible in one dataframe of course so I split them in two dataframes now I want to take these 2 dataframes and get the top 3 indexes (indexes not values) so far I'm doing it separately   taking top 3 values and then df2 <- as.numeric(rownames(df2))
df2  it's working but it's not a good and generic code obviously, I want to do it in generic way

Comment: @r2evans thanks for the suggestion, so the dataframes are already in a list and all I should do is look for functions to apply on each dataframe in the list, right?

Comment: Yes. Two short demos: `lapply(data, head, n=2)`, or more generically `sapply(data, function(df) mean(df$x))`.

Comment: @r2evans Thank you sooo much it works perfectly fine! however if I apply it to find the indexes it doesn't work df<-lapply(df,as.numeric(row.names(df))) I can get the values using lapply(df, "[[", 1) but I don't want the values but the indexes

Comment: First, read `?lapply` (the second argument must be a function). Perhaps read [Hadley's "Functionals"](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functionals.html) (and perhaps more of his online tutorials/book). Next, `as.numeric(row.names(...))` is bad form, what are you trying to accomplish with it? (At the risk of question-creep.)

Comment: The time is quite short actually but I will read these :/ I want to get the indexes of values in dataframes, I used to do it seperatly before like  `df1<- head(df$7,k) df2<- head(df$8,k)` and then `df1<- as.numeric(row.names(df1))
df2 <- as.numeric(row.names(df2))`

Comment: Got it done using df<-lapply(df, rownames)

Comment: And, so, answer your own question as you have rightly worked it through to completion, or suggest that the author of the most informative comment write the answer. My thoughts, interesting discussion.

Comment: Thanks @Chris I will do that and give credit to r2evans :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @r2evans I got it done, here is his code from the comments

> Yes. Two short demos: lapply(data, head, n=2), or more generically
>   sapply(data, function(df) mean(df$x)). – r2evans

and after that fetching the indexes

```
df<-lapply(df, rownames)
```